# Cannot resolve symbol Assert for Android

Tags: java, android

I have a project that I use openVpn. I cannot implement "Assert" related libraries. How do I do that?
*junit cannot be found*

```
import  org.junit.Assert;//not found

if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Assert.assertEquals("dev", routeparts[3]);
```

Comment: Are you sure JUnit is installed on the correct class path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your import statement to `import org.junit.Assert.*;`

```
import  org.junit.Assert.*;

if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Assert.assertEquals("dev", routeparts[3]);
```

Comment: @HasanKucuk Try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.`, check your compile statement and do resync of the gradle.

Comment: @HasanKucuk Check if your build variant is on release instead of debug?

Comment: @HasanKucuk Also (these might seem obvious, but still worth checking anyway) check if file is in /test (not androidTest) directory, check if the `testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'` is in your app's top-level `build.gradle` file.